# gnumake pattern subsituation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Having some trouble with GNUMAKE `$(subst)` I cannot explain
My goal is to transform a "SRC_DIR" directory into an "OBJ_DIR"
In one case it works, the other it does not - I do not understand why.

I thought, that the two "HERE{1|2}" constructs below would be identical, it seems they are not.
I do not believe it is a "delayed execution" problem because I am using the := (evaluate now, immediately in all cases)

```
PROJ_ROOT :=$(HOME)/a
BUILD_DIR :=$(PROJ_ROOT)/build/debug

HERE1:=$(shell pwd)
HERE2:=`pwd`

OK1 := $(subst $(PROJ_ROOT),$(BUILD_DIR),$(HERE1))
BAD := $(subst $(PROJ_ROOT),$(BUILD_DIR),$(HERE2))
TEST=$(subst ee,EE,feet on the street)

all:
    @echo PR=$(PROJ_ROOT)
    @echo BR=$(BUILD_DIR)
    @echo H1=$(HERE1)
    @echo H2=$(HERE2)
    @echo OK1 is $(OK1)
    @echo BAD IS $(BAD)
    @echo TEST=$(TEST)
```

The output is below, the OK1 is correct,
but BAD is wrong It should be the same ask OK1

```
PR=/home/foobar/a
BR=/home/foobar/a/build/debug
H1=/home/foobar/a/src/one/two/three
H2=/home/foobar/a/src/one/two/three
OK1 is /home/foobar/a/build/debug/src/one/two/three
BAD IS /home/foobar/a/src/one/two/three
TEST=fEEt on the strEEt
```

background:  I have a large project (400+ source files) spread over about 10 directories, each directory has a src folder, ie:  $(PROJECT_ROOT)/libfoo/src/foo.c, and $(PROJECT_ROOT)/libbar/src/bar.c - Unlike the "autoconfigure" method where SRCDIR != BUILD_DIR (you configure in the build dir, and create makefiles in the build dir, I am doing the opposite - I have a prebuilt makefile that should create/populate a build directory structure with object files.

To do that, I need to create various subdirectories under $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build" that MIRROR the source folders. For example the makefiles should create: $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/debug/libfoo/src/foo.o, and $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/debug/libbar/src/bar.o

thus I need to 'slice the 'lib{foo|bar}/src and paste this into/onto the root of the build directory using makefile tricks.

Comment: The `HERE2` assignment using backticks doesn't execute the `pwd` command.  It's simply (as far as I know) parsed as the text string "\`pwd\`" by `make`.

Comment: *...spread over about 10 directories...* - 10 is not a lot. Just list them and update on 11th etc. Speaking from experience, regrettably.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
HERE1:=$(shell pwd)
HERE2:=`pwd`
```

The first line runs the make `shell` function and sets the value of `HERE1` to the result of running the `pwd` command, which is what you expected.  The second line sets the value of `HERE2` to the literal string `` `pwd` ``.

When you use `subst` on the string `` `pwd` `` obviously nothing happens.

Once again, people are led astray by premature addition of `@`.  Never, ever, **ever** add `@` to your recipes until after your makefile works completely.

If you removed the `@` from the lines that used `HERE2` then it would be immediately obvious why things worked differently.  Make would print out the command it was going to run and you could see that `HERE2` is not replaced *by make* but that it's the shell that is running the `pwd` command:

```
echo H2=`pwd`
H2=/home/foobar/a/src/one/two/three
```

and:

```
echo BAD IS `pwd`
BAD IS /home/foobar/a/src/one/two/three
```